# PHP not detecting empty POST variables

Tags: php

I have the following array

```
Array ( [productid] => 3
[newid] => 3
[name] => 
[description] => 
[price] => 
[onlinestock] => 
[weight] => 
[keywords] => 
[longdescription] => 
[graphic1] => 89.jpeg 
[graphic2] => 
[parameter1] => 
[parameter2] => 
[category1id] => 101 
[category2id] => 
[category3id] => 
[category4id] => 
[category5id] => 
[extra1] => 
[extra2] => 
[extra3] => 
[group1id] => 1575 
[groupprice1] => 0 
[group2id] => 1576 
[groupprice2] => 0 
[group3id] => 1577 
[groupprice3] => 0 
[group4id] => 1578 
[groupprice4] => 0 
[group5id] => 1579 
[groupprice5] => 0
```

I'm doing the following to check for empty values

```
 if (empty($_REQUEST["category1id"])){ 
                $_REQUEST["category1id"] = 0;
        }else if (empty($_REQUEST["category2id"])){
                $_REQUEST["category2id"] = 0;
        }else if (empty($_REQUEST["category3id"])){
                $_REQUEST["category3id"] = 0;
        }else if (empty($_REQUEST["category4id"])){
                $_REQUEST["category4id"] = 0;
        }else if (empty($_REQUEST["category5id"])){
                $_REQUEST["category5id"] = 0;
        }else if (empty($_REQUEST["price"])){
                $_REQUEST["price"] = 0;
        }else if (empty($_REQUEST["onlinestock"])){
                $_REQUEST["onlinestock"] = 0;
        }else if (empty($_REQUEST["weight"])){
                $_REQUEST["weight"] = 0;
        }
```

but somehow it's not detecting any of these values as empty? I'm not sure what this could be I tried $_REQUEST['category1id'] == "" and that also is not working. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you are only looking for POST variables use `$_POST`, not `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: look on : http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php .The following things are considered to be empty:

    * "" (an empty string)
    * 0 (0 as an integer)
    * "0" (0 as a string)
    * NULL
    * FALSE
    * array() (an empty array)
    * var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your logic is flawed. By using `else if`, only the conditions will match where the previous condition returned `false`. Get rid of each `else` and it should work.

Comment: true fixed it, and it worked, silly from me to have had the else there ;-) Thanx

Answer (score 4):

Pekka is 100% correct.  But I think it would be easier to change your approach.  Replace your entire `if/else` block with this loop:

```
foreach ($_POST as &$post) {
    $post = empty($post) ? 0 : $post;
}
```

Comment: btw, for those that do not know what the `$post = empty(....` is, it is a Ternary Operator (http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 2):

Good comments above, main thing is don't use $_REQUEST:

`$_REQUEST contains: $_COOKIE, $_GET, and $_POST variables`

if you use $_REQUEST you have no guarantee that the data came from the POST, which leads to security holes in your script.  Explicitly declare what you want $_POST/$_GET.

Also read the `empty()` fn documentation

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Take a look at `isset()` as well -- (Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL):

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to dwell into what is going on there. Sometime times for what you were trying to do I've used isset. The else if answer should be taken into account.